# Programming pattern for heap compaction?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

Is there an Android programming pattern for heap compaction. Like that the app says "good bye" for a while, closes the UI, and then comes back with its UI?

It seems that the current Android design is such, that they don't want longer jank “perceptible.", and decided to do compaction only for background apps.

According to this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39747070/9307810

I could imagine a dialog that ask either for abort or compaction. When the end-user chooses compactionen how would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

> When the end-user chooses compactionen how would this be done?

It wouldn't. There is no way to force the GC to perform heap compaction.

> Is there an Android programming pattern for heap compaction

Compaction is handled by the runtime, for whatever version of Android you are running on.

Your focus should be on ensuring that your process terminates in a timely fashion (i.e., avoid continuously-running services) and avoiding unnecessary memory retention (e.g., clear caches in `onTrimMemory()` callbacks, for appropriate trim levels).

> and decided to do compaction only for background apps

I believe that GC will perform some compaction even for foreground apps as of Android 8.0.

Comment: How can you background and then forground your own app, from within the app. The say "good bye" from my question. Maybe show a small clock running somewhere. I guess a background app is not completely terminated, so I don't need to persist the memory state.

Comment: I am already using onTrimMemory(). But onTrimMemory() is useless for a forground app, if the heap is fragement, and if compaction cannot be run. Even if you release resources, what I do, I release tons of resources, since heap is fragement, the app cannot recover in the foreground.

Comment: Ok, I see, wait for Android 8.0. Thanks!